# how to cause a supervolcanic eruption

Tags: weapons, geology

I want to make use of the [Toba Catastrophe Theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toba_catastrophe_theory) in my story. From Wikipedia:

> The Youngest Toba eruption was a supervolcanic eruption that occurred around 75,000 years ago at the site of present-day Lake Toba in Sumatra, Indonesia. It is one of the Earth's largest known explosive eruptions. The Toba catastrophe theory holds that this event caused a global volcanic winter of six to ten years and possibly a 1,000-year-long cooling episode.

According to the theory, this reduced human population to just a few thousand individuals, taking us to the brink of extinction.

In my story, the Toba Catastrophe was caused by aliens. Their tech level at the time was roughly that of ST:TNG. Just like... conventional sci-fi tech. They were trying to wipe out humanity in a way that would leave some plausible deniability.

What plausible scenarios are there for them to have caused the supervolcanic eruption? Would a big bomb or orbital bombardment do it? Bonus points if there's a way for them to accidentally trigger it in the course of a massive, global bombardment, but I'll take a targeted, precision-engineered trigger if that's required.

Comment: It's your story, don't bother to explain it. After it is done, go on to something more exciting, and your readers will probably have no problem.

Comment: @JBH the title litterally says "how", but reading between the lines of the text (last paragraph esp) I'm guessing it should be "why". Your right the "how" is very well covered, but the why not so much.

Comment: @Ash "why" is even worse. The rationale of why an alien species would cause the explosion is 100% story-based and off-topic.

Comment: @Ash I see a how actually. The why is covered (plausible deniability in genocide), but how would you do such a plausible deniability scenario.

Comment: From a strictly scientific point of view the bottleneck hypothesis is ad acta, never was really a thing in Paleo-Anthropology (not a theory, a suggestion basedon mt dna, deprecated meanwhile), mostly hype. Humans thrived well through those times, in India, Africa, Asia and Europe there are lots of findings. Knowledgeable aliens wouldn't bother with such uncertainties. Just have them nuke/bombard/throw asteroids/install space mirrors to heat up/radiation ... whatever. As direct as possible :-)

Comment: Do your aliens have ANY level of directed gravity control? It they can induce a reduced gravity over a deep area of the Earth, even a fraction of a fraction of a fraction of a percent, the mantle will promptly form a rising convection plume in that location, resulting in a most spectacular volcano some time later.(months to a few years). and it should be a biggie! Best of all, after the plume is in motion, they can switch off the interference and even leave the scene, the effect will be self-sustaining,.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found good answers in an article at Wired: https://www.wired.com/2012/04/could-people-trigger-a-volcanic-eruption-on-purpose/

From that article:

- Find a volcano that is already showing some signs of magma intruding at shallow depths. This might be high levels of volcanic gases, shallow earthquakes, deformation of the volcano. You want something "primed" to go.
- Figure out a way to release the lithostatic pressure keeping the "cork" on the volcano so that the bubbles can form.
- Figure out how to get a lot of water into the volcano quickly ... but not too quickly.

So, answering my specific questions:

"What plausible scenarios are there for them to have caused the supervolcanic eruption?"

The first two seem relatively easy: since it's based on the real-world Toba eruption, they just need to detect that it's near eruption. Since the Wired article specifically mentions a grid-pattern of explosives on the surface, I can probably get close enough with an orbital bombardment in a grid pattern.

The third is the tricky one: how to get a bunch of water introduced? I'll think of something, now that I know it's an ingredient.

"Would a big bomb or orbital bombardment do it?"

It could play a role, but isn't enough on its own.

"Bonus points if there's a way for them to accidentally trigger it in the course of a massive, global bombardment, but I'll take a targeted, precision-engineered trigger if that's required."

The accidental scenario is unlikely. The bombardment would have to be specifically targeted, and then on top of that you need to introduce the water.

FWIW: I **did** search this before I posted. I got discouraged when I found a ton of spurious articles. Even after going back (after TBH reprimanded me) I still only found that one Wired article (reprinted at Discover) that was useful. Most of the others are about trying to *defuse* volcanic eruptions, and really don't answer the question. Even more are about model volcanoes.

Oh well.

Answer (score 0):

If this civilization has the ability to create artificial gravity, one possibility could be using said technology to pull magma up from the mantle, creating a massive eruption.  Alternately, if they've got teleportation technology, they could easily use it to inject a large quantity of water into the planet's crust.  The water would then expand massively due to geothermal heating, forcing the eruption.

It always surprises me how no one in-universe seems to think of all the ways their futuristic tech could be creatively misused.

Answer (score -1):

#### They started teraforming a planet populated with intelligent life

I've heard theories on when Australia first got human life ranging from 60,000 to 120,000 years, and methods of transport ranging from island hoping in canoes from Asia to walking across in an ice age. This is within the timeframe of this eruption, and I think the arrival of humans in this region can be part of the scenario.

- Aliens land in North Australia. Look around and decide this planet will do nicely if they just do a bit of lite teraforming.
- The aliens deliberately set off the volcano to cool temperatures down a bit, step one of their plans. (We want to smash ice asteroids into Mars so violent things are par for the course here).

  - Sustained orbital bombardment will be plausible in this genre of sci fi - powerful explosive rounds that penetrate far into rock should do the trick. The audience wont know how unstable and close to blowing the volcano was before the bombardment started. It may of been going to blow anyway and they just moved it forward a few decades.
- The resulting ice age allows humans to migrate from Asia to Indonesia to Australia on foot. Or forces them to migrate because it destroys their food sources.
- Humans and aliens see each other, aliens realise they've broken the rules and humans meet the minimum requirements of being on the planet first.
- Aliens scamper off hoping no one can identify them.

Comment: Please do not answer questions that violate the rules (if you're right that the OP is asking for "why" and not "how" then this question is VTC:Too Story-Based).